# mailgun report to csv format perl

Tags: perl, batch-file, join, split, mailgun

I have a question.  I would like to write a perl script to parse a Mailgun output to a csv format.  I would assume the 'split' and 'join' functions would work properly for this procedure.  Here is some sample data:

**Sample Data**

```
{

    "geolocation": {

    "city": "Random City", 

    "region": "State", 

    "country": "US"
    }, 
    "url": "https://www4.website.com/register/1234567", 

    "timestamp": "1237854980723.0239847"
}


{

    "geolocation": {

    "city": "Random City2", 

    "region": "State2", 

    "country": "mEXICO"
    }, 
    "url": "https://www4.website2.com/register/ABCDE567", 

    "timestamp": "1237854980723.0239847"
}
```

**Desired Output**

"city","region","country","url","timestamp"

"Random City","State","US","https://www4.website.com/register/1234567","1237854980723.0239847"

"Random City_2","State_2","mEXICO","www4.website2.com/ABCDE567","1237854980723.0239847_2"

My goal is to take my Sample data and create the desired output as a comma delimited CSV file.  I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.  Normally I would try to hack through this with a series of one-liners in a batch file, but I would prefer a perl script.  The real data will contain more information.  However, just figure out how to parse the general structure will be fine.

Here is what I have in a batch file.

**Code**

```
    perl -p -i.bak -e "s/(,$|,+ +$|^.*?{$|^.*?}.*?$|^.*?],.*?$)//gi" file.txt

    rem Removes all unnecessary characters and lines with { and }. ^

    perl -p -i.bak -e "s/(^ +| +$)//gi" file.txt    

    perl -p -i.bak -e "s/^\n$//gi" file.txt


rem Removes all blank lines in initial file. Next one-liner takes care of trailing and beginning 

rem whitespace.  The file is nice and clean now.

perl -p -e "s/(^\".*?\"):.*?$/$1/gi" file.txt > header.txt

rem retains only header info and puts into 'header.txt' ^

perl -p -e "s/^\".*?\": +(\".*?\"$)/$1/gi" file.txt > data.txt

rem retains only data that is associated with each field.

perl -p -i.bak -e "s/\n/,/gi" data.txt

rem replaces new line character with ',' delimiter.

perl -p -i.bak -e "s/^/\n/gi" data.txt

rem drops data down a line

perl -p -i.bak -e "s/\n/,/gi" header.txt

rem replaces new line character with ',' delimiter.

copy header.txt+data.txt report.txt

rem copies both files together.  Since there is the same amount of fields as there are data   

rem delimiters, the columns and headers match.
```

**My Output**

"city","region","country","url","timestamp"

"Random City","State","US","https://www4.website.com/register/1234567",1237854980723.0239847

This does the trick but a condensed script would be better.  Varying situations will affect this batch script I need something more solid.  Any suggestions??

Comment: use [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single Perl script with one regex

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;

$_ = <<TXT;
{

    "geolocation": {

    "city": "Random City",

    "region": "State",

    "country": "US"
    },
    "url": "https://www4.website.com/register/1234567",

    "timestamp": "1237854980723.0239847"
}
TXT

my @matches = /\s*\s*("[^"]+")\s*\s*:\s*("[^"]+")/gmx;
my %hash = @matches;

say join(",", keys %hash);
say join(",", values %hash);
```

Which output this:

```
"city","country","region","timestamp","url"
"Random City","US","State","1237854980723.0239847","https://www4.website.com/register/1234567"
```

Of course if you want to use STDIN instead you replace the string definition with:

```
local $/ = undef;
$_ = <>;
```

If you desire a more robust code, I suggest to first matching the data block contained into braces. Then you would search for key:values.

I would write this `program.pl` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = undef;    
open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die $!;
$_ = <FILE>;
close FILE;

# Match all group { ... }
my @groups = /((?&BRACKETED))
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<WORD>     [^\{\}]+ )
    (?<BRACKETED> \s* \{ (?&TEXT)? \s* \} )
    (?<TEXT>      (?: (?&WORD) | (?&BRACKETED) )+ )
)/gmx;

# Match any key:value pairs inside each group
my @results;
for(grep($_,@groups)) {
    push @results, {/\s*\s*"([^"]+)"\s*\s*:\s*("[^"]+")/gmx};
}

# For each result, we print the keys we want
for(@results) {
    say join ",", @$_{qw/city region country url timestamp/};
}
```

Then one batch file to call the script:

```
rem How to call it...
@perl program.pl text.txt > report.txt
```

Comment: I like your answer. It worked they way I wanted it to, but check out the edit I just made on my question. Look at desired output and the re-edited sample data I provided. What if there were 2 sets of data? So The csv would contain the header we extracted and then beneath it would be data row 1, data row 2 and so on.  @coin

Comment: @JDE876 the second version of script will output what you are expecting: two lines for each city. But rather than using a regex to parse your data, I would suggest to use a JSON parser.

Comment: is there any possible way that you could provide an example of substituting the regex with the JSON parser?  @coin

Comment: The above comment is just for an applied example's sake.  Otherwise the regex does work wonders thanks to the modifiers you have provided i.e. gmx, global, and multi-line matches.  :) @coin

Answer (score 0):

Not to scoff at @coin's regex-fu, but advantages of using CPAN modules include getting a more flexible solution that you can build on down the road, and taking advantage of edge-case handling that other folks have already worked out.

This solution uses a JSON module to parse your incoming data (I'm assuming it continues to look like JSON), and the CSV module to produce high-quality CSV, which takes care of things like embedded quotes and commas inside your data.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON qw/decode_json/;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $json_data_as_string = <<EOL;
{
    "geolocation": {
        "city": "Random City", 
        "region": "State", 
        "country": "US"
    }, 
    "url": "https://www4.website.com/register/1234567", 
    "timestamp": "1237854980723.0239847"
}
EOL

my $s = decode_json($json_data_as_string);

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1 });

$csv->combine(
    $s->{geolocation}{city},
    $s->{geolocation}{region},
    $s->{geolocation}{country},
    $s->{url},
    $s->{timestamp},
) || die $csv->error_diag;;

print $csv->string, "\n";
```

To read the data from a file into $json_data_as_string, you can use the code from @coin's solution.